# How to stop queuing of operations on a control?

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a tab control in the WPF application. Inside the tabcontrol each tab item consists of so many check boxes and buttons. Each check box when it is clicked, in background with a new thread, some operation is going. Till that completes tabcontrol's isHitTestVisible is made false, so that any other click should not happen. But now the problem is, that while the operation isn't complete nothing is happens, but the clicks are queued and after completion it they are executed. So how can I avoid queuing of operations. What is required is when an operation is running, if something is clicked it should not do anything. For this I have made ishittestvisible as false but now it is queuing up. So please help how to go ahead.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the Enabled = false on the checkbox while the operation is processing?

Comment: i have done that. But after operation completes, i have made Enabled = true. But still operations are getting queued up.

Comment: I saw that, when ui thread is made busy with the operation and Application.doevents is called i am getting what i want. But the operation which is used is not connected to ui thread. Can only tab controls thread can be suspended and after completion can it resume?